# Conditional Entropy and Mutual Information - Clustering evaluation

Tags: clustering, model-evaluations, information-theory, mutual-information

First of all, I am doing clustering and I have the true labels for my data.
For evaluation, I am using the weighted average of the entropy values for each predicted cluster. I also came across with Mutual Information as a similar approach while going over the alternatives. On my data, they seem to give similar results.

However there is one issue that puzzles me.

Given the predicted cluster set $U$ and true clusters $V$, mutual information was defined as:
$$ I(U,V) = H(U) - H(U|V) $$
or,
$$ I(U,V) = H(V) - H(V|U)  $$
If my math is correct, the average entropy that I'm using corresponds to conditional entropy term $H(V|U)$ and trying to minimize this aligns with maximizing the mutual information.

What I cannot see is how weigthed average entropy would differ from mutual information and why we would need the entropy terms $H(U)$ or $H(V)$. It feels like minimising one of the conditional entropies should suffice.

To put it another way, as far as I understood from the equations, having high entropy for true or predicted clusters in itself also results in higher mutual information. Does this mean that mutual information favors equally-sized clusters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutual information does favor many small clusters. Nectar these tend to be "pure". That is why variations, such as *normalized* mutual information and adjusted mutual information (AMI), are used instead.

> Vinh, N. X.; Epps, J.; Bailey, J. (2009). "Information theoretic measures for clusterings comparison". Proceedings of the 26th Annual International Conference on Machine Learning - ICML '09. p. 1. doi:10.1145/1553374.1553511.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! It also suggests normalized information distance (NID) as a general purpose measure.

Comment: There was also some follow-up that argues for different adjustments for chance.

Comment: I did not take a close look on adjusted and normalized versions. So, they essentially prevent the metric from favoring any particular number of clusters. Thank you!

Comment: They don't adjust for the number of clusters. They adjust for random permutation of labels with the *same* cluster sizes. AFAICT, NMI still favors many small clusters.